# How to dynamically construct javascript object name?

Tags: extjs

In ext js , lets us say there is a variable like this:

```
var obj1 = {x: 'x string', y: 'y string'}
```

If I wish to replace the names 'x' and 'y' with something dynamic e.g:

```
var v1 = some value  
var v2 = some value
```

and i want:

```
var obj1 = {result of v1: 'x string', result of v2: 'y string'}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, off the top of my head, add your own error checking as desired:

```
function replaceKey(myObject, oldKeyName, newKeyName) {
   if (myObject[oldKeyName]!==undefined) {
      myObject[newKeyName] = myObject[oldKeyName];
      delete myObject[oldKeyName];
   }
}
```

Which for the variables in your question you could call like this:

```
replaceKey(obj1, "x", v1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of directly arriving at:var obj1 = {result of v1: 'x string', result of v2: 'y string'}  without having to do : var obj1 = {x: 'x string', y: 'y string'} and then : replaceKey(obj1, "x", v1); ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do (from your original question I thought you meant you wanted to rename properties that already existed), but would this do what you're asking: var obj1 = {}; obj1[v1] = "x string"; obj1[v2] = "y string";